# c# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException inserting a new record

Tags: c#, linq

I've created an import system in my application.

I start from an upload of a JSON, this JSON is received as string from my web service, then transformed in an object called `tpp` (I've checked and my object is correctly created and populated).

Then I do some inserts in my database:

```
db.States.Add(tpp);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It works fine. Then, `tpp` contains `cities`, so I use this code:

```
foreach (City curCity in tpp.Cities)
   {
   db.Cities.Add(curCity);
   db.SaveChanges();
   }
```

In this `db.SaveChanges()` I receive a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` regarding saving foreign keys.

tpp.Cities contains a list of Streets (`List<Street> Streets` in my City class), but I save them later in another table and also States contains a list of Cities but it doesn't throw an exception.

So, why my code is returning an exception when I add a city in foreach loop?

Comment: it'd be helpful so see the Cities entity or table structure.

Comment: Could you share the Cities entity class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data structure on the POCOs and incoming JSON is right than you shouldn't have to add the child items manually. From your code it appears it is. So just adding the ttp should take care of everything as long as ***ttp.Cities.Streets*** ... and so on are populated.